# Minimum value of $f(x) = x^3 + 9x^2 + 5$ on $[0,3]$

Tags: calculus

> For the function $f(x) = x^3 + 9x^2 + 5$ on the interval $[0,3]$, determine the minimum value.

I don't know how to do this. I think we have to find the derivative and set that equal to $0$, but that wasn't giving me the right answer. Any ideas?

Comment: You mean minimum value?

Comment: The minimum is either in the interval $(0,3)$, then $f'$ is zero there, *or* it is at an *endpoint* of the interval: at $x=0$ or $3$.

Comment: That's what I thought, but the question states "Determine the minimum function"

Comment: @Berci, the answer is: 5

Comment: Could you insert the derivative you calculated in the question?

Comment: @Berci, $f'(x) = 3x^2 +18x$

Comment: On $[0, 3]$, $x^3$ is non-negative, so the minimum value is $5$ at $x = 0$. No need for calculus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that we want to find the minimum value of the function.

Take the derivative of the function, so

$$f'(x) = 3x^2 + 18x$$

If $f'(x) = 0$, then

$$0 = 3x(x + 6)$$
$$x = 0 \text{ and } x = -6$$

Since $x = -6$ is not within the interval, neglect that.

Then, by checking the values of the endpoints, we have $f(0) = 5$ and $f(3) = 113$.

Thus, the minimum value is 5.

Here is the [good picture of the graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3+%2B+9x%5E2+%2B+5+for+0+%E2%89%A4+x+%E2%89%A4+3) of that function with $[0, 3]$.

Comment: This solution relies on two facts.  One, a continuous function on a closed interval must have a minimum and a maximum there.  Two, for any continuous function on any interval (closed or not), minimums and maximums occur at points where the derivative is zero, or where the derivative is undefined, or endpoints of the interval (if they are included in the interval).  Combining these means we must have a min and a max, and both must occur only at certain spots, as mentioned above.  In this case, the $x$ values 0 and 3 are the only possibilities, so 5 is the min at 0 and 113 is the max at 3.